# Why is AWS S3 so slow? (Swift)

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 to store profile pictures for user accounts on an iOS app using swift.. I am able to get the pictures I want from S3, but it takes a very long time for them to load. I don't know why this is happening. Is that just how S3 works, or is there a better way to do things? This is my code for downloading the picture:

```
let downloadingFilePath1 = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("temp-download")
        let downloadingFileURL1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: downloadingFilePath1)
        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
        let readRequest1 : AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
        readRequest1.bucket = "groopapictures"
        readRequest1.key =  self.searchTextField.text
        readRequest1.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL1

        transferManager.download(readRequest1).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
            println(task.error)
            if task.error == nil {
                self.ppImageView.hidden = false
                println("Fetched image")
                self.ppImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: downloadingFilePath1)

            }
            return nil
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check which queue you're running on in your return block. If it's not the main queue, setting the `image` property of a `UIImageView` can take a long time to be "noticed" and updated. Test this by putting the image assignment line inside a `dispatch_async()` to the main thread.

If that doesn't help, run Charles and see how long S3 is taking to return the image.

Comment: That sounds like it might be right, but I have no idea how to do that, could you provide an example?

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

The downloading speed may get vary based on your bucket created region and your accessing location. Make sure to choose the region which is geographically near to your location while creating the bucket in AWS S3.

[This image taken from amazon s3 documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13VIr.png)

You can refer Amazon s3 documentation in following [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) to get idea about bucket region.

Thanks!